# How do I append for index to a v-model?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm doing a for loop and I want to append the index to the value/v-model/value of the i`on-input`

```
     <div v-for="n in names" :key="n">
       <ion-item>
         <ion-label>Name {{n}}</ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" v-model="name{{n}}" value="name{{n}}"> </ion-input>
       </ion-item>
    </div>
```

But I'm getting an error:

> error    Parsing error: ',' expected

So probably it's not how it's supposed to work. I also tried `v-model="name[n]"`, `v-model="name:n"` and `v-model="name+n"`

**My question is:**

How can I append the `for` index to the v-model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use index, and create new array for dynamic models:

```js
    <div v-for="(n, index) in names" :key="n">
       <ion-item>
         <ion-label>Name {{n}}</ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text" v-model="newArray[index]"> </ion-input>
       </ion-item>
    </div>
```

Check dynamic models: `<p> {{ newArray[0] }}.. </p>`

Comment: Thank you. I guess it worked...I don't know because I had to remove "NewArray" in order to display the `index`...but I believe it works in `v-model`.

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães newArray is there to store values from inputs, but ok, if you need index only :)